# Is it possible to add pagination to questions, to easily navigate through them?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I often find myself scrolling down the questions in the "Newest" category and <kbd>⌘</kbd> + Clicking the links (opens in new tab), so I don't lose my place in the list.

This prompted me to think *"What if I could just click 'Next' and move to the next question in the list?"* Much the way you can navigate posts on WordPress:

[image]

I know that pagination is not a new thing, or even a thing that's difficult to integrate. I think it could be a nice feature, to have "Previous" and "Next" buttons at the top and bottom of each question page.

- Has this ever been discussed?
- Why was it shot down, if so?
- Am I the only one that would be interested in this?

Comment: think this would be better on meta.se

Answer (score 6):

> Has it ever been discussed?

[Next/previous question button?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243619/next-previous-question-button)

> Why was it shot down, if so?

Not much traction or strong reasons why such a feature makes sense

- Most want to see questions that interest them
- Chronological order on here has very little meaning

> Am I the only one that would be interested in this?

I won't say you're the only one but I can't imagine many people wanting to go through. I also agree with the person in the meta post linked above's observation that it will encourage, "Speeding." Essentially people clicking next, next, next, short answer, next, short answer, short answer, next, next, next. The site generally works best when people focus on the topics they're knowledgeable and enthusiastic about.

Comment: I searched for "pagination" and "question navigation" but couldn't find that post.  I'll have a look now.  I guess I just like to browse, especially topics I don't know about.  I like to read and learn, so the 'million tabs open' system of mine has some room for improvement, but I guess it's just me hah